# How to revert changes in VS Code

Tags: visualstudiocode

I have retrieved all my Apex Controllers, VF Pages and Triggers to VS Code and made few changes to the controllers. I deployed the changed version of code to source org and terminated the VS Code. Is there any possibility that I can revert all changes in VS Code after few hours of time. If there is any way of doing it can someone help me. Its an emergency.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Always use a Version Control System, such as [git](https://git-scm.com/). You'll find various cloud-based repository providers available, such as [GitHub](https://github.com) and [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/). This means you don't have to remember to back up your repository yourself. I know this is a bit late to consider if you're not already doing so, but can avoid future pain.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in VS Code unless you have a history extension(like in Intellij.idea) or GIT enabled for project. I don't think the VS code creates a temp directory.

You can try retrieving the code from another sandbox which has same code or move over to version in system (Atleast local repository) in the future.